# Why is mongoose queries working without exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I am rather inexperienced in mongoose, but I have a fairly large project now that relies on it. Recently I began trying to get a deeper understanding of the complicated structure of mongoose.

One of the things that I was suprised by in the docs is that everyone insists that `exec()` is neccessary to execute any queries.

What I don't understand is that I have been using queries like these and not had a problem.

```
await User.findById(userOne._id)
await User.find({})
await User.find({ friends: 3 }).limit(50).skip(2)
```

Is is all due to the `async`/`await` nature?

What's occurring here??

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs, you can use both. The main difference seems to be that when you use .exec() you have a better stack trace.

In terms of functionality, they are equivalent.